# Magento 1 : How to add search option for Attribute manage options?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have added an attribute "Student Registraion No" in admin which have 24773 records. I want to a check a particular "Student Registration No." that no. is  added or not, but I could not check easily. I open one by one page and check no.

So, how to add a search option like product list in admin?
[image]

Comment: are you want to check all Student Registration No is included in product attribute selection? means list of registration no which is not assign to product

Comment: Yes sir. which is not assign to product or which is not added. Because I have more registration number list, I want to add but I am founding which are add or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create one php file in root with below code and execute file url.
using below script you can get all Student Registration No which is still not assign.
Just replace `Your Attribute Code` with your attribute code in below script

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'Your Attribute Code'); //"color" is the attribute_code
  $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
  foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $flag = 0;
        $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

           if($_product->getColor() == $id) 
           {
                $flag = 1;
           }

        }
        if($flag == 0)
        {
            echo  $instance['label'].'<br>';
        }
  }
```

Comment: I want searching option by attribute Options like product search on product listing (by sku, product name, attribute set. product type, price qty etc.) in admin.